# remove rows with more than one unique value for one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `table1` and `table2` - i want to merge these tables with any duplicate `emp + carno` rows removed. For example below  - rows with `emp` as `mike` needs to be removed as `mike` has more than one unique `carno` in `table1`. Similarly rows with `emp` as `sara` need to be removed as `sara` has more than one unique `carno` across `table1` and `table2`.

**table1**

```
+------+---------+
| emp  |   carno |
+------+---------+
| mike |  mh01   |
| sara |  mh02   |
| luke |  mh01   |
| mike |  mh04   |
+------+---------+
```

**table2**

```
+------+---------+
| emp  |   carno |
+------+---------+
| dave |  mh01   |
| sara |  mh06   |
| nite |  mh07   |
+------+---------+
```

**output**

```
+------+---------+
| emp  |   carno |
+------+---------+
| luke |  mh01   |
| dave |  mh01   |
| nite |  mh07   |
+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with appropriate logic.  The basic stategy I used here is to union together the two tables, and then apply `COUNT` as an analytic function to figure out which employees appear in quantities greater than one.  Then, restrict the union result to include only employee records where he or she appears once.

```
INSERT INTO output (emp, carno)
SELECT emp, carno
FROM
(
    SELECT emp, carno, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY emp) cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT emp, carno FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT emp, carno FROM table2
    ) t1
) t2
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Here is what the output of the outer select gives:

[image]

**Edit:**

The answer by @zarruq is more efficient than this one, because it eliminates one subquery.  But my approach can easily be adapted to filter out employees on any cardinality, with no change in performance.

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all` in inner query to combine data from both tables and`aggregation` along with `having count(emp) = 1` to filter out the employee with more than one record in outer query as below..

```
select t.emp, min(t.carno) as carno from 
(
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
) t
group by t.emp
having count(t.emp) = 1
order by carno;
```

**Result:**

```
emp     carno
--------------
dave    mh01
luke    mh01
nite    mh07
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BYHU26297)**

---

**Update:**

You can use `INSERT INTO tablex(emp, carno) SELECT .....` to insert the output to a table

```
insert into tablex (emp, carno)
select t.emp, min(t.carno) as carno from 
(
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
) t
group by t.emp
having count(t.emp) = 1
order by carno;
```

**[INSERT-SELECT DEMO](http://rextester.com/MEGILW44918)**

Comment: yeah. this is an efficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

> for deleting from multiple tables with different key

```
  delete a,b from table1 a innerjoin table2 b on b.carno != a.carno where a.emp ='mike' or b.emo = 'sara'
```

u can use variables instead of static by select query

```
Select a.emp as name1,b.emp as name2 from table1 a innerjoin table2 b on b.carno != a.carno
```

here u need to execute query and get name1 and name2 and save it into variable

```
delete a,b from table1 a innerjoin table2 b on b.carno != a.carno where a.emp ='$name1' or b.emo = '$name2'
```

> for multiple entries in same table
>
> first select

```
select count(*) as total from table1 where emp ='mike'; //or emp = '$yourvariable'

here u need to execute query and get total as count
if(total!=1)
{
delete a from table1 a where name ="mike"
}
```